# Static Query vs Dynamic Query Performance in Progress 4GL

Tags: oracle, database-performance, progress-4gl, openedge

I am executing a static Query on DB with 50k Records. Its taking 2 minutes to get executed.
Is there any chance to improve query performance by making that query Dynamic?
I am using open edge 10.2 version and Oracle DB.

Comment: By making that query dynamic you definitely won't improve its performance. 50k not that many records. It also would be a good idea to provide that query, performance of which you are trying to improve, and explain plan

Answer (score 1):

No, a dynamic query will, at best, be equal in performance to a static query.  If you do try a dynamic query make sure to set FORWARD-ONLY.  Otherwise a result set will need to be maintained on the client in order to (potentially) move backward in the query and this will degrade performance.

Two minutes for 50,000 records is much more likely to be an index selection problem.  Your WHERE clause probably isn't bracketing the data appropriately.  You might also just have a (very) badly tuned database or server.

Answer (score 0):

bulk collect should improve performance (though as others have said already there is probably another issue with the index / query etc)

```
select <fields> bulk collect into <table_type> from <table> where <things are true>
```